# YA novel: boy and girl adventure in a forest, one ends up moving away

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a book with a very colorful cover about a boy and a girl who lived near each other and would meet on this hill every day in the summer to adventure through this forest. They make up spirits that guide them and ones that hurt them. The children are pretty young but I remember them touching each other at one point I think. At one point, they fall asleep in a flower bed, and at another, the girl falls into a river. Maybe. At the end, one of the kids moved away which really bummed me out because it seemed like they were going to get married or something. I also think the mother was an alcoholic or a drug addict but the main chunk of this books was these kids adventure in a forest. The book was pretty descriptive and beautifully written.

Comment: Are you certain all of these elements are from the same novel? Because some of it (especially the girl falling into a river) sounds VERY much like the Bridge to Terabithia.

Comment: I am very sure. I have never read Bridge to Terabithia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was [Too Far](http://www.toofar.com/) by Rich Shapero. I thank you all for your help, anyway. I highly recommend it. It's a great read.

[image]

> On the outskirts of Fairbanks, six-year-old Robbie meets a mesmerizing girl his own age, and together they explore the mysterious woodland surrounding their homes. The world they discover is built from their fantasies, and inhabited by creatures born from their dreams.
>
> But while Robbie and Fristeen grow inseparable, Robbie’s parents are drifting apart, and Fristeen’s mother is coming undone. As their homes become increasingly unstable, the children travel deeper and farther into their private world. The forest—and the gods who inhabit it—becomes their refuge until, at summer’s end, they are forced to choose between the crushing prospects of the real world, and the lethal demands of their ideal one.

Answer (score 6):

I think the book you are referring to is *[Bridge to Terabithia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_to_Terabithia_(novel))*.

[image]

> It's the story of fifth grader Jesse Aarons, who becomes friends with his new neighbor Leslie Burke after he loses a footrace to her at school. She is a smart, talented, outgoing tomboy, and he thinks highly of her. He is an artistic boy who, in the beginning, is fearful, angry, and depressed. After meeting Leslie, his life is transformed. He becomes courageous and learns to let go of his frustration.

Comment: No sir, it is not. This book is more poetic almost, and the cover is veryy colorful. It looks sort of like a watercolor pointing.

Comment: Ok my apologies. Is there a way for me to remove my answer so I don't get negatives because I really felt that it was The Bridge to Terabithia.

Comment: Hopefully people wouldn't give you negatives for that. Was my first guess too.